# Return values instead of objects in filter() method

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, foreach

I have this simple code:

```js
function getStockOver(stocks) {
    'use strict';
    return stocks.filter(function (stock) {
        return (stock.price > 150);
    });
}

var stocks = [
    { symbol: 'XFX', price: 240.22, volume: 23432},
    { symbol: 'TNZ', price: 110.22, volume: 232},
    { symbol: 'JXJ', price: 340.22, volume: 5632}
];
var symbols = getStockOver(stocks);

console.log(symbols);
```

Check if the `stock.price > 150` through `.filter()` then return it, otherwise skip it.
But I want to return only the `price` in the new array that created through `.filter()`, not the whole object, How?

***Note:*** I know this can be done through `.forEach()` but `.filter()` is way easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just add [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for the price only.

```js
function getStockOver(stocks) {
    'use strict';
    return stocks.filter(function (stock) {
        return (stock.price > 150);
    }).map(function (stock) {
        return stock.price;
    });
}

var stocks = [
    { symbol: 'XFX', price: 240.22, volume: 23432},
    { symbol: 'TNZ', price: 110.22, volume: 232},
    { symbol: 'JXJ', price: 340.22, volume: 5632}
];
var symbols = getStockOver(stocks);

console.log(symbols);
```

Answer (score 4):

You want reduce, not filter

```
var stocks = [
    { symbol: 'XFX', price: 240.22, volume: 23432},
    { symbol: 'TNZ', price: 110.22, volume: 232},
    { symbol: 'JXJ', price: 340.22, volume: 5632}
];
var results = stocks.reduce( function (a,o) { if(o.price > 150) a.push(o.price); return a; }, []);
console.log(results);
```

Comment: Thank you for this, very useful, But may I ask How to return the results in new Object not Array?

Comment: So why are you not using filter if you want it like the orginal?

Comment: Like this `results = {
    price: 240.22,
    price: 340
}` not sure If this can be done or not, I've tried to start with empty object as initial value.

Comment: That is impossible. An object can not have the same key.

Comment: Oops, did not notice that :D, I will stick with your reduce method, I am thankful.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this in a single line. These built in functions are made for exactly this purpose.

```
symbols = stocks.filter(function(stock){
    return stock.price > 150
}).map(function(stock){
    return stock.price;
});
```

You could also do something a little more complex with objects:

```
var StockList = function( _data ) {
    this.data = _data;
};
StockList.prototype.getStocksOver = function( overPrice ) {
    return new StockList(this.data.filter(function (stock) {
        return stock.price > overPrice;
    }));
};
StockList.prototype.getPrices = function() {
    return this.data.map(function (stock) {
        return stock.price;
    });
};

var stocks = new StockList([
    { symbol: 'XFX', price: 240.22, volume: 23432 },
    { symbol: 'TNZ', price: 110.22, volume: 232 },
    { symbol: 'JXJ', price: 340.22, volume: 5632 }
]);

var pricesOver150 = stocks.getStocksOver(150).getPrices();

console.log(pricesOver150);
```